# Minor variations between sentences

Tags: difference

> 1. My phone calls drop too frequently.
> 2. My phone calls drop frequently.

The difference between above two sentences is minor (only the word "too").

Actually I am working on a project of summarizing sentences, and I have to prove that the above sentences mean the same. So, I want to ask is there any established paper/work/method to prove this?

Comment: You may use the option of 'edit' [(click here)](http://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/69979/edit) the question to improvise or clarify your doubts rather than posting the same question. I closed the other one marking it 'duplicate'. And, I changed this one for what you wanted to convey.

Answer (score 3):

You may find this a bit more difficult than you expect, because those sentences *don't* mean the same thing. When you call something "too frequent", you mean that it's more frequent than it should be, or that it should be less frequent (which is the same thing). So the first sentence is basically complaining about phone calls dropping, while the second is just making a fairly neutral observation.

Comment: The question has been changed. You may need to edit the answer accordingly.